# "IoT includes devices that/which are connected to the internet"

Tags: relative-pronouns

I've studied about how to use "that" or "which", but I'm still confused about which one to choose in this sentence:

> IoT includes devices **that/which** are connected to the internet.

which one is correct?

Comment: The sentence is strange to start with and so is not very helpful in exploring relative pronouns. Where did you see it? Did you write it yourself? I’d say something like, “The internet of things **involves** devices that are connected to the internet.” Using includes seems forced.

Comment: Use *that* for restrictive relative clauses, those necessary for the definition of the thing they modify.

Comment: What's the intended meaning re the "restrictive" and "non-restrictive" aspect you want to convey? In short, if it's "non-restrictive", use *which*; otherwise you can choose.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie I've written it myself. Should I use *the* with "internet of things"?

Comment: Yes, I’d use the definite article “the” with both IoT and the unabbreviated term. I notice Wikipedia does, for example: *“This can only be possible with **the** IoT and its seamless connectivity among devices.”*

Comment: Back to the heart of the question though. Yes, a grammatically valid sentence is, “The IoT includes devices **that** are connected to the internet.” *But*, I’m concerned the sentence is meaningless. It is almost analogous to saying, “The USA includes States that are in the United States.” **Includes** is the wrong choice of word. Only  something like **is made up of**, instead of **includes**, makes this sentence communicate anything meaningful. There is otherwise something very obvious and circular about the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a restrictive clause here, so “that” is the most appropriate choice from my perspective. “Devices **that** are connected to the internet” are the subset of all devices that you want here and together it is these devices that wholly define the Internet of Things (IoT).

There is a second issue here. You normally use the definite article “the” with “Internet of Things” and its abbreviation, IoT. For example, from the Wikipedia entry for the IoT: *This can only be possible with **the** IoT and its seamless connectivity among devices.*

There remains a third issue. I’m concerned the sentence doesn’t convey much meaning and ‘includes’ may be a poor choice of word.

The sentence you propose is almost like saying, “The USA includes States that are in the United States.” ‘Includes’ here is the wrong choice of word. A better, but still strange, sentence might be: “The USA **is made up of** States that are in the United States.”

Your sentence similarly might be improved if “includes” were changed to “consists of” or “involves”. There is otherwise something very obvious and circular about the sentence.

So, in conclusion, you may be happier with this sentence:

> The IoT involves devices that are connected to the internet.

Notice too that with restrictive clauses “that” can be omitted, so the sentence could be:

> The IoT involves devices connected to the internet.